# Существительное после предложения

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Сегодня я узнал, как называется в некоторых крупных компаниях необходимый офисному работнику поход в туалет. Биопауза. Биопауза, блин.

Какой синтаксической конструкцией является слово **биопауза**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Сегодня я узнал, как называется в некоторых крупных компаниях необходимый офисному работнику поход в туалет. **(1) Биопауза. (2) Биопауза, блин.***

Я думаю, что первое предложение является неполным, так как это ответ на вопрос "как называется".

А вот во втором предложении с помощью междометия дана дополнительная **ироническая оценка** этого названия.

Поэтому это не номинативное предложение, а **изолированный номинатив со значением оценки**,  так как "свое функциональное качество он приобретает в результате воздействия предшествующего контекста".

https://studfiles.net/preview/2682296/